# Generate a random number with no repeating digits?

Tags: c++, random

I'd like to generate a random number with each digit being in range from 0-9 and not repeating itself. Assume finite length of 4.

- 1234 qualifies, each composite digit is unique.
- 1123 does not, 1 is repeated

How can this be done please?

Comment: The digits shouldn't be repeated within the number, or the number itself should be different from any previously generated number?

Comment: @jogojapan, I'd like for each number in the list to be different: 1234 qualifies. 1123 does not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate the digits:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // or initialize from array if not c++11
std::random_shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.resize(4);
```

And to join the digits into a single number:

```
int number = 0;
for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i) {
    number = 10 * number + (*i);
}
```

Comment: I would just use an array from the start, `std::vector<int>` gains us nothing here. But good answer! Also note this may give a leading zero, which reduces to a three digit number.

Comment: I wish we had Python's `random.sample` in C++ :)

Comment: This is great, but for some reason same numbers are always generated:  `7 3 1 9`,  `6 3 5 1` , `7 2 0 5` , `6 0 5 9` , `8 7 1 3`

Comment: @JamesLeonard: Well, did you seed your random number generator?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about generating permutations.

Try something like this:

```
int used[10] = {0};
int n = 0;
int number = 0;

while( n < 10 ) {
    int d = rand() % 10;
    if( used[d] ) continue;
    used[d] = 1;
    number = number * 10 + d;
    n++;
}
```

Not the most efficient...  It simply tracks what digits have been used, and rerolls any time a used digit is encountered.

The above does have the side-effect that zero is technically not used if it's the first number chosen.  You could explicitly prevent this, or simply accept that some numbers will be 9 digits long.

Comment: hmm, your question changed after answers were given.  I'm sure you can adapt accordingly.

Comment: @pst yes, I acknowledged that.  I like the answer using STL.  Didn't know about that function.  Another approach is to generate an array of 0-9, and then swap random pairs of digits multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather avoid needless use of std::vector and the memory allocations it brings, excessive randomisation calls presumably used within random_shuffle, there's a simpler approach if you play with some math.

If you can count how many valid (i.e. acceptable) sequences exist, *C*, and you can devise a bijective function that maps from this counter to each valid sequence instance then things become trivial. Generate a random integer in the range [0,*C*), plug that into your function which returns the valid output.

If I understand your example correctly, you want to generate a random 4 digit sequence ABCD (representing an integer in the range [0,9999]) where digits *A*, *B*, *C* and *D* are different from one another.

There are 5040 such valid sequences: 10 * 9 * 8 * 7.

Given any integer in the range [0, 5039], the following function will return a valid sequence (i.e. one in which each digit is unique), represented as an integer:

```
int counter2sequence(int u) {
  int m = u/504;
  u %= 504;
  int h = u/56;
  u %= 56;
  int t = u/7;
  u %= 7;

  const int ih = h;
  const int it = t;

  if (ih >= m) ++h;
  if (it >= ih) ++t;
  if (t >= m) ++t;
  if (u >= it) ++u;
  if (u >= ih) ++u;
  if (u >= m) ++u;

  return ((m*10 + h)*10 + t)*10 + u;
}
```

E.g.

```
counter2sequence(0) => 0123
counter2sequence(5039) => 9876
```