# Four digit random number without digit repetition

Tags: c++, random

Is there any way you can have a 4 digit number without repetition - e.g. not `1130` but `1234`? I read `std::random_shuffle` could do this but it would only swap the numbers in between.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

unsigned seed = static_cast<size_t>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

using namespace std;

class Player {
private:
    string playername;

public:
    void setName(string b) {
        cout << "Please enter your name:" << endl;
        getline(cin, b);
        playername = b; 
    }

    string getName () {
        return playername;
    }
};

class PasswordGuessingGame {
private:
    std::mt19937 random_engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> random_generator;

public:
    PasswordGuessingGame():
        random_engine(seed),
        random_generator(1000,9999)
    { 
    }

    int getNumber () {
        return random_generator(random_engine);
    }
};

int main () {
    Player newgame;
    PasswordGuessingGame b;
    newgame.setName("");

    cout << newgame.getName() << " " <<  "password " << b.getNumber() <<  endl;
    }
```

Comment: Just pick again if there's duplication.

Comment: "it would only swap the numbers in between". What do you mean by this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random number with no repeating digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048175/generate-a-random-number-with-no-repeating-digits)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to generate a string containing the digits, and to use the C++14 function `std::experimental::sample()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <experimental/algorithm>

int main() {
std::string in = "0123456789", out;
do {
    out="";
    std::experimental::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), 4, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    std::shuffle(out.begin(), out.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
  } while (out[0]=='0');
  std::cout << "random four-digit number with unique digits:"  << out << '\n';
}
```

**Edit:**

Changed to prevent a result that starts with a 0. Hat tip to @Bathsheba who indicated that this could be a problem.

Comment: Cute (plus one), but depends if you think 0123 is 3 or 4 digits. Also, what's the warranty attached to std::experimental?

Comment: @Bathsheba: You get all your money back if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to generate each digit separately. For example you have array from 0 to 9 with 0..9 digits. For first digit you generate number from 0 to 9 and pick up digit from this array. Then you swap this array element t with last element of array. For second digit you generate number form 0 to 8. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with `std::random_shuffle`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::string s;    
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(s), 10,
        []() { static char c = '0'; return c++; });
    // s is now "0123456789"

    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());

    // if 0 can't be the first digit
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(1, 9);
    std::swap(s[0], s[dist(gen)]);

    // shuffle the remaining range
    std::shuffle(s.begin() + 1, s.end(), gen); // non-deprecated version

    // convert only first four
    auto x = std::stoul(s.substr(0, 4));
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbea042af18060d4)

Answer (score 0):

If you can count how many valid (i.e. acceptable) sequences exist, and you can devise a bijective function that maps from this counter to each valid sequence instance then things become trivial.

If I understand your example correctly, you want to generate a random 4 digit sequence ABCD (representing an integer in the range [0,9999]) where digits *A*, *B*, *C* and *D* are different from one another.

There are 5040 such valid sequences: 10 * 9 * 8 * 7.

Given any integer in the range [0, 5039], the following function will return a valid sequence (i.e. one in which each digit is unique), represented as an integer:

```
int counter2sequence(int u) {
  int m = u/504;
  u %= 504;
  int h = u/56;
  u %= 56;
  int t = u/7;
  u %= 7;

  const int ih = h;
  const int it = t;

  if (ih >= m) ++h;
  if (it >= ih) ++t;
  if (t >= m) ++t;
  if (u >= it) ++u;
  if (u >= ih) ++u;
  if (u >= m) ++u;

  return ((m*10 + h)*10 + t)*10 + u;
}
```

E.g.

```
counter2sequence(0) => 0123
counter2sequence(5039) => 9876
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using only standard data and numeric algorithms.

```
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

template<class Engine>
int unrepeated_digits(int ndigits, Engine &eng) {
    std::array<int, 10> digits = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    auto add_digit = [](auto x, auto digit) {
        return x * 10 + digit;
    };
    std::shuffle(std::begin(digits), std::end(digits), eng);
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(digits), std::next(std::begin(digits), ndigits), 0, add_digit);
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rnd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rnd());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << unrepeated_digits(4, eng) << std::endl;
}
```

example output:

```
7623
3860
9563
9150
3219
8652
4789
2457
1826
9745
```